# Why is $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{1} \neq \binom{n}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

$$
\binom{n}{1}\cdot\binom{n-1}{1} = n \cdot (n-1),
\qquad\text{whereas}\qquad
\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}. $$

It's quite obvious that LHS $\ne$ RHS.

But intuitively we know, as per the definition of $\binom{n}{r}$,

$\binom{n}{1}\cdot\binom{n-1}{1}$ is the equivalent of selection $1$ out of '$n$' objects, followed by selecting $1$ out of '$n-1$' objects (since we have already selected $1$ object, the total number of objects is now '$n-1$').

And, $\binom{n}{2}$ is the equivalent of selecting $2$ out of 'n' objects. Since we're selecting $2$ different objects, it should be the same as selecting $1$ out of '$n$' objects, then another $1$ out of '$n-1$' objects.

I'm sure there is some sound logic for the difference between the $2$ expressions, but it isn't occurring to me. I would be grateful if someone could enlighten me on the **reason** for the difference betweeen the two.

Here is my question: **Why** is $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{1} \neq \binom{n}{2}$?

Comment: Because picking $\{i,j\}$ corresponds to two possibilities -pick $i$ then pick $j$, and pick $j$ and then pick $i$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3914147/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7B1%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn-1%7D%7B1%7D%20%5Cneq%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7B2%7D%24)